# Can anyone tell me what this symbol is

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a code like this

```html
<li role="presentation">
  <a
    href="#Twistato"
    class="rounded btn"
    aria-controls="Twistato"
    role="tab"
    data-toggle="tab">
    Twistato
  </a>
</li>;
```

I get a symbol like an image below

[image]

can anyone tell me what this symbol is or its name or how I can find it

Comment: Unfortunately, that character isn't in the snippet you created. Be sure to highlight the full relevant lines and use copy and paste to put them in the question (no need for a snippet, just use Ctrl+K to mark it as code). (Alternately: It may be from CSS via `content` on a `::before` or `::after` rule, etc.)

Comment: Probably a background image somewhere - look in Developer Tools.

Comment: That symbol means that the css is referencing a missing font. Check the css file.

Comment: That's what Firefox shows when it encounters a character that it doesn't have a glyph for. Looking closely at your screenshot, it's [U+F0DD](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=F0DD), which is not an assigned character in Unicode (no characters in the range D800-FFFF are assigned, because that's the range used by surrogate pairs in UTF-16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it was a dropdown icon which was given a default value

```css
.the-menu-custom-nav .nav-tabs > li > a:before {
        content: '\f0dd';
        top: 7px; }
```

i removed and its fine now